# Are illegal drug names offensive?

Tags: discussion, display-names, offensive

I stumbled on to a user whose name is an illegal drug: [Crystal Meth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3186758/crystal-meth)

Is this "offensive" or otherwise unacceptable?

My opinion is that this is not an acceptable username.

Comment: What exactly is offensive about it?

Comment: If you nuke him, [two](http://stackoverflow.com/users/289748/cocaine112358) [more](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1919382/cousincocaine) for you.

Comment: Not the second one @ShadowWizard. That's just the first one's cousin.

Comment: And what about all the users that are named Lucy?  That is slang for LSD.  This is the problem with deciding what is offensive and what isn't... where do you draw the line?

Comment: A lot of drug names aren't resolvable anyway such as heroine (a female hero) or not illegal everywhere (even in the US) such as cannabis or a drug which is also used legally in vetenary practice or human medicine such as ketimin or codine

Comment: OK! I'm obviously a prude... :/ I got my answer :)

Comment: Nobody is perfect, @Bohemian and we all taste the bitter side of Meta sometimes. :-)

Comment: Frankly I consider this a validation of your position as a mod; asking the community rather than just applying your opinion, so +1, but I also disagree so -1, but its a discussion rather than a feature request so +1 overall! (Not that I really like downvoting well written feature requests either)

Comment: You know, questions like this are usually better asked/answered in the TL.  :)

Comment: @Wont I disagree,  this is a question for the community and so better answered out here

Comment: @Won't yeah, but I wanted to see what the wider community thought. I guess I found out - this ain't a Christian youth group blog :/

Comment: What gave you the impression we were @Bohemian? ;)

Comment: @RichardTingle: You don't have to ask every one of your stupid questions in public.  Wait, did I say this was a stupid question?  No, really, I didn't mean it that way.  Cereal.

Comment: well he already nuked me :(

Comment: Interesting topic, I do not agree with your opinion, but I found the question useful. +1 for leaving a -29 question up and not giving into peer pressure.

Comment: Ha, I just ran across this news article the next day.  Someones real name [Crystal Metheney](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2656325/Woman-named-Crystal-Metheney-arrested-not-think.html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Drugs are bad for you, m'kay. Don't do drugs kids, m'kay.

That said, I don't think the name is offensive at all. If it is, please also do something about [Blue Ice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/229501/blue-ice). With Ice being slang for crystal meth, and Breaking Bad still on our mind, surely that's crossing a boundary as well.

But no, just because certain things are not that great for your health, doesn't mean their name becomes offensive.

Comment: **+1** "Someone's username is Crystal Meth. I gotta go do drugs!" **said no one ever.**

Comment: Then again, I do shog on occasion @michaelb958. If only I could resist that urge.

Comment: To be noted here, Even Shog is a username here! :D I guess he's a moderator too hehe..

Comment: Welp, that escalated quickly.

Comment: Quit being so offensive @BlueIce ;)

Answer (score 24):

Its just a name, who said a username would cause someone to use it. You're having a username: **Bohemian**, that doesn't force me to go and Drink the Bohemia Wine.

[image]

This really does makes sense! Before imposing something onto others, you **must** take a note of that on yourself!

According to me, everyone has right to do what so ever he wants to do! So, if he has a name that **he may/may not** knowingly used after the Drug name, its ok! Now its upto you, to donot use it in the bad ways! :-)

Comment: Not kidding: now that you mentioned Bohemian, I *do* have a Queen's song playing in my brain now. Of course, that's some weird wiring in my head.

Comment: @Arjan, there is a Punjabi (Language and Culture of South Asia) Rapper named **BOHEMIA** too, there are many things ressembling our names, Mercedes, Honda, etc! Now one should give up using them or start buying them if he doesn't have them? nah! That's so insane...

Comment: YEAH RIGHT!!! well bohemian also made a post about me.

Comment: that's below the belt @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan

Answer (score 6):

Such usernames are neither more nor less offensive than any other username.

Offence is in the eye of the beholder.

I have seen users with names based on sexual innuendo that some people would find offensive.  If rules were to be put in place regarding username selection, where would they end?

Comment: We do sometimes moderate names, but your feeling is generally spot on here; It's easy to find offense in lots of things. Something has to be pretty bad. Usually such names are *intentionally* offensive and come with other behavior, too. But as you note, sexual innuendo, for example, would not at all be automatically 'banned'. It would have to be something very strong, direct, and very broadly offensive. Anyway, +1

Answer (score -3):

I absolutely believe these names are offensive. There are some terms that one just shouldn't use as a username. Crystal Meth and intelligent discussion *usually* don't mix well.

Comment: If we accept this, we would likely have to moderate on sight a user named TheCobolAndVisualBasicGuru. Do we really want that?